# Divison by zero error while using two recyclerviews

Tags: java, android, math

Hi I am making an app where I am using two recyclerviews as to make a layout the first part of layout I am making using [this](https://github.com/thunderpunch/LadderLayoutManager) and second part using [this](https://android-pratap.blogspot.in/2015/12/horizontal-recyclerview-in-vertical.html).
Now my problem is when I try to use the second recyclerview with first one it is giving me divide by zero error.
My code where I am getting error and this code ID from the first link I have given please any help would be appreciated.

```
  public int getFixedScrollPosition(int direction, float fixValue) {
        if (mCheckedChildSize) {
            if (mScrollOffset % mChildSize[mOrientation] == 0) {
                return RecyclerView.NO_POSITION;
            }
            float position = mScrollOffset * 1.0f / mChildSize[mOrientation];
            return convert2AdapterPosition((int) (direction > 0 ? position + fixValue : position + (1 - fixValue)) - 1);
        }
        return RecyclerView.NO_POSITION;
    }


    @Override
    public void onMeasure(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state, int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(recycler, state, widthSpec, heightSpec);
        mCheckedChildSize = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLayoutChildren(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state) {
        if (state.getItemCount() == 0) {
            removeAndRecycleAllViews(recycler);
            return;
        }
        if (!mCheckedChildSize) {
            if (mOrientation == VERTICAL) {
                mChildSize[0] = getHorizontalSpace();
                mChildSize[1] = (int) (mItemHeightWidthRatio * mChildSize[0]);
            } else {
                mChildSize[1] = getVerticalSpace();
                mChildSize[0] = (int) (mChildSize[1] / mItemHeightWidthRatio);
            }
            mChildPeekSize = mChildPeekSizeInput == 0 ?
                    (int) (mChildSize[mOrientation] * DEFAULT_CHILD_LAYOUT_OFFSET) : mChildPeekSizeInput;
            mCheckedChildSize = true;
        }
        int itemCount = getItemCount();
        if (mReverse) {
            mScrollOffset += (itemCount - mChildCount) * mChildSize[mOrientation];
        }
        mChildCount = itemCount;
        mScrollOffset = makeScrollOffsetWithinRange(mScrollOffset);
        fill(recycler);
    }

    public void fill(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler) {
        int bottomItemPosition = (int) Math.floor(mScrollOffset / mChildSize[mOrientation]);//>=1 //this is the line giving error
        int bottomItemVisibleSize = mScrollOffset % mChildSize[mOrientation];
        final float offsetPercent = mInterpolator.getInterpolation(
                bottomItemVisibleSize * 1.0f / mChildSize[mOrientation]);//[0,1)
        final int space = mOrientation == VERTICAL ? getVerticalSpace() : getHorizontalSpace();

        ArrayList<ItemLayoutInfo> layoutInfos = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = bottomItemPosition - 1, j = 1, remainSpace = space - mChildSize[mOrientation];
             i >= 0; i--, j++) {
            double maxOffset = mChildPeekSize * Math.pow(mScale, j);
            int start = (int) (remainSpace - offsetPercent * maxOffset);
            ItemLayoutInfo info = new ItemLayoutInfo(start,
                    (float) (Math.pow(mScale, j - 1) * (1 - offsetPercent * (1 - mScale))),
                    offsetPercent,
                    start * 1.0f / space
            );
            layoutInfos.add(0, info);

            if (mMaxItemLayoutCount != UNLIMITED && j == mMaxItemLayoutCount - 1) {
                if (offsetPercent != 0) {
                    info.start = remainSpace;
                    info.positionOffsetPercent = 0;
                    info.layoutPercent = remainSpace / space;
                    info.scaleXY = (float) Math.pow(mScale, j - 1);
                }
                break;
            }
            remainSpace -= maxOffset;
            if (remainSpace <= 0) {
                info.start = (int) (remainSpace + maxOffset);
                info.positionOffsetPercent = 0;
                info.layoutPercent = info.start / space;
                info.scaleXY = (float) Math.pow(mScale, j - 1);
                break;
            }
        }

        if (bottomItemPosition < mChildCount) {
            final int start = space - bottomItemVisibleSize;
            layoutInfos.add(new ItemLayoutInfo(start, 1.0f,
                    bottomItemVisibleSize * 1.0f / mChildSize[mOrientation], start * 1.0f / space).
                    setIsBottom());
        } else {
            bottomItemPosition -= 1;
        }

        int layoutCount = layoutInfos.size();

        final int startPos = bottomItemPosition - (layoutCount - 1);
        final int endPos = bottomItemPosition;
        final int childCount = getChildCount();
        for (int i = childCount - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            View childView = getChildAt(i);
            int pos = convert2LayoutPosition(getPosition(childView));
            if (pos > endPos || pos < startPos) {
                removeAndRecycleView(childView, recycler);
            }
        }
        detachAndScrapAttachedViews(recycler);

        for (int i = 0; i < layoutCount; i++) {
            fillChild(recycler.getViewForPosition(convert2AdapterPosition(startPos + i)), layoutInfos.get(i));
        }
    }

    private void fillChild(View view, ItemLayoutInfo layoutInfo) {
        addView(view);
        measureChildWithExactlySize(view);
        final int scaleFix = (int) (mChildSize[mOrientation] * (1 - layoutInfo.scaleXY) / 2);
        final float gap = (mOrientation == VERTICAL ? getHorizontalSpace() : getVerticalSpace())
                - mChildSize[(mOrientation + 1) % 2] * layoutInfo.scaleXY;

        if (mOrientation == VERTICAL) {
            int left = (int) (getPaddingLeft() + (gap * 0.5 * mVanishOffset));
            layoutDecoratedWithMargins(view, left, layoutInfo.start - scaleFix
                    , left + mChildSize[0], layoutInfo.start + mChildSize[1] - scaleFix);
        } else {
            int top = (int) (getPaddingTop() + (gap * 0.5 * mVanishOffset));
            layoutDecoratedWithMargins(view, layoutInfo.start - scaleFix, top
                    , layoutInfo.start + mChildSize[0] - scaleFix, top + mChildSize[1]);
        }
        ViewCompat.setScaleX(view, layoutInfo.scaleXY);
        ViewCompat.setScaleY(view, layoutInfo.scaleXY);
        if (mDecorateHelper != null) {
            mDecorateHelper.decorateChild(view, layoutInfo.positionOffsetPercent, layoutInfo.layoutPercent, layoutInfo.isBottom);
        }
    }

    private void measureChildWithExactlySize(View child) {
        RecyclerView.LayoutParams lp = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
        final int widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                mChildSize[0] - lp.leftMargin - lp.rightMargin, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        final int heightSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(
                mChildSize[1] - lp.topMargin - lp.bottomMargin, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        child.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec);
    }

    private int makeScrollOffsetWithinRange(int scrollOffset) {
        return Math.min(Math.max(mChildSize[mOrientation], scrollOffset), mChildCount * mChildSize[mOrientation]);
    }
```

LogCat

```
java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero at
 int bottomItemPosition = (int) Math.floor(mScrollOffset / mChildSize[mOrientation]);//>=1
```

Comment: So... And now... who is going to tell why it is zero? And why are you dividing by it if it is zero?

Comment: Hi @Green apps thanks for reply but i'm not dividing it by zero as i said in my question i used code with other recyclerview which is not working and giving this error

Comment: @Smith are sure mChildSize[mOrientation] is not zero , use debugging

Comment: Hi @nima_moradi i have checked it happens only when i'm trying to use  horizontal recyclerview inside vertical recyclerview